# Wave file - processing specific chunk of audio data

Tags: c#, arrays, naudio, wave

I'm trying to iterate over a wave file and send **20ms** of it every iteration.
Assuming I'm using a **8khz, 1 channel, 16bit** audio file, I have the below code using NAudio:

```
WaveFileReader wHeader = new WaveFileReader(fullFileName);

byte[] data = new byte[wHeader.Length];
int read = wHeader.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
short[] sampleBuffer = new short[read / 2];
short[] InpBuf;

for (int i = 0; i < read; i += 2)
{
InpBuf = new short[159]; //20ms?

Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, sampleBuffer, 0, read);
InpBuf = sampleBuffer;

Process20(InpBuf); //Send 20ms of audio data which inside InpBuf 

}
```

I can see that the complete audio data is inside **sampleBuffer** now (generated wave sine) but I cannot divide these 20ms into **InpBuf** and I see that **InpBuf** contains the whole audio data.

Once I understand this issue I'll be able to move on to stereo and different audio formats.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the blockcopy operation

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, sampleBuffer, 0, read);
```

you are copying the whole input buffer from start each time because you have not defined any offset

see [BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation

Comment: Thanks. What is the best thing to do in here?

Should it be something like this or is there any other efficient way?

`code
int offst = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < read; i += 2)
            { 
                Buffer.BlockCopy(data, offst, InpBuf, 0, 159);
                offst += 159;

               Process20(InpBuf); //Send 20ms of audio data which inside InpBuf 

                Array.Clear(InpBuf, 0, InpBuf.Length);
            }
code`

Comment: it is good for the first approach ... probably it can be tweaked a little bit as soon as you are sure that it is working as expected

Comment: Unfortunately, this brings a very confusing result...
My original Audio data is inside 'byte[] data = new byte[wHeader.Length];'

When I'm looping the Audio data it looks like this:
'for (int i = 0; i < read; i += 2)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(data, offst, InpBuf, 0, tBuf);
                offst += tBuf;

                Array.Clear(InpBuf, 0, InpBuf.Length);
            }'
However, inside InpBuf I'm seeing the first half ok, and then I get zeros till the end, and afterwards the values are different that the data.

I might miss the whole point in here...